# i want to add a background image to my customize message box but i am not able to get it

Tags: c#-4.0, windows-phone-8

This is my code it is showing error in the BitmapImage

```
CustomMessageBox messageBox = new CustomMessageBox()
    {
        Caption = "Congratulations",
        Message = "you have won",
        LeftButtonContent = "Play Again",
        RightButtonContent = "FB Share",
        VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center,
        Background = new BitmapImage(new Uri("/imaC:/Users/Rupak/Documents/Visual Studio 2012/Projects/sachin/sachin/image.png")),
        Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black),

    };
```

Comment: Try different Uri("/image.png",UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute) - if the image is in the root folder of the project.

Comment: it is showing the error bitmapimage could not be found

Comment: i tried imagesource instead of bitmapimage still it is showing some error

Comment: Try to copy your image in your project folder and set uri to /YourProject/Images/image.png,urikind.relativeorabsolute. And you image can't be found because it isn't in your project.

Answer (score 1):

You are doing it wrong, because `CustomMessagebox.Bacground` is `Brush`. You cannot put there BitmapImage, ImageSource and other.

It will fine work if you put there:

```
Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red),
```

In fact there is in Windows Phone something like ImageBrush but as I test it it won't work with that easy with CustomMessageBox:

```
ImageBrush mybrush = new ImageBrush() {ImageSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri("/Resources/firstImage.png", UriKind.Relative)) };
```

It won't work because in [WPToolkit](http://phone.codeplex.com/) source code there is something like this ([License to code](http://phone.codeplex.com/license)):

```
 // (c) Copyright Microsoft Corporation.
 // This source is subject to the Microsoft Public License (Ms-PL).
 // Please see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=131993 for details.
 // All other rights reserved.

 // Insert the overlay.
 Rectangle overlay = new Rectangle();
 Color backgroundColor = (Color)Application.Current.Resources["PhoneBackgroundColor"];
 overlay.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(0x99, backgroundColor.R, backgroundColor.G, backgroundColor.B));
 _container = new Grid();
 _container.Children.Add(overlay);
```

As you can see `Grid` is overlayed with `Rectangle` which is filled with `SolidColorBrush`, not the `Brush` (`ImageBrush`) you have set.

Comment: yes it is working when i am using                                                  Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red),                            But can you tell me how to use background image  in the message box

Comment: I've edited the answer and added the reason why it is not possible.